Automatic volume migration following the pod
I have k8s test cluster with 1 master and 2 worker nodes.
I created a PersistentVolumeClaim resource using the Hetzner Cloud csi driver. This driver only allows you to create ReadWriteOnce volumes.
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: metadata
  namespace: development
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: hcloud-volumes

I also created a Deployment resource with one Pod that uses that volume.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app1
          image: some-image
          volumeMounts:
            - name: metadata
              mountPath: /mnt/metadata

      volumes:
        - name: metadata
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: metadata

Overall everything works great. The pod was tied to a specific node to which the volume was assigned (for example worker-2).
The problems start when I turn off worker-2. Deployment resources tries to recreate the pod on another node (worker-1), but gets stuck in deadlock, since the PersistentVolumeClaim is busy with the old pod.
Specific error: Multi-Attach error for volume "pvc-f587e0c2-25f1-4792-815e" Volume is already used by pod(s) app1-5f9c445458
Is there any way I can make a volume automatically unmount from a pod using this volume type? I would like to have a deployment resource that can easily migrate a pod from one node to another, along with its associated volumes.
